# How can I Display currentUsers -> Name. Using RealTime Database

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I want to Display logged user's username. I am using the firebase realTime database, not the cloud firestore.

I am looking at different methods like Stream Builder, Datasnap shot. Anything that works is welcomed

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../services/auth.dart';
import 'home.dart';
import 'settings.dart';
import 'package:shadow_app_project/data_models/user_profile_browse.dart';
import 'package:shadow_app_project/image_selection/user_edit_image.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class SettingsUI extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsUI({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Setting UI",
      home: EditProfilePage(),
    );
  }
}

class EditProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditProfilePageState createState() => _EditProfilePageState();
}

class _EditProfilePageState extends State<EditProfilePage> {

  TextEditingController displayNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController ageController = TextEditingController();
  bool isLoading = false;
  User? user;
  UserProfileBrowse? userModel;
  String? imageUrl;
  final refDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  bool showPassword = false;
  final userName = "Name";
  final userAge = "age";

  String name = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('userProfileBrowse/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}/name').toString();

  var usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .ref()
      .child('userProfileBrowse/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}');

  String currentUserEmail = (Auth().auth.currentUser as User).email.toString();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ref = refDatabase.ref();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        elevation: 1,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => const SettingsPage()));
          },
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.settings,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => const SettingsPage()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: usersRef.onValue,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 25, right: 16),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
              },
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    "Edit Profile",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 130,
                    height: 130,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                            width: 4,
                            color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              spreadRadius: 2,
                              blurRadius: 10,
                              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                              offset: const Offset(0, 10))
                        ],
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        image: const DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: NetworkImage(
                              "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3307758/pexels-photo-3307758.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=250",
                            ))),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 35,
                  ),
                  Text(userName,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    // initialValue: name,
                    controller: displayNameController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                  ),
                  Text(userAge,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    // initialValue: ,
                    controller: ageController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  ),
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text("Email: ", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                  ),
                  Text(currentUserEmail,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 35,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text("CANCEL",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                letterSpacing: 2.2,
                                color: Colors.black)),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                         ref.child('userProfileBrowse/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}/name').set(displayNameController.text);
                         print("updating name");
                         ref.child('userProfileBrowse/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid}/age').set(ageController.text);
                         print("updating age");
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          "SAVE",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              letterSpacing: 2.2,
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Should I even stream builder in my code?
I just want to display my logged user's name in my TextFormField initialvalue: name,

Comment: It is quite complicated using Realtime Database, I advice you to use Firebase Firestore instead. Let me know if you need help concerning that!

Comment: I know right. But it just my team is working with it and I don't have many tutorials on real-time database sadly :(